# Pass PDO (InnoDB) transaction to new class

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, pdo, innodb

I have a class which crawls a page a gathers information from the page.  It then starts a transaction and starts adding information to different tables (to make sure all or none of the information gets updated, as I have had some problems with multi-curl not always returning complete pages).  Then, if the content saved is new, the class calls a notifications class which saves these notifications to a database and sends emails.  I want the information saved in the notification class to be contained as part of the original transaction, so if something fails later on the user won't receive a notification.

I thought I would just pass the current pdo handle (with the open transaction) to my new notification class and work from there. When I use this pdo handle to insert rows, rollback, and exit the script from the notification class, the inserted rows stick to the database (i.e., don't rollback).  I confirmed that the data inserted with the same pdo handle in the original class was successfully rolled back.  I thought I would try to start a transaction in the notification class (even though this is not ideal for the structure of the application), but I got a PDOException 'There is already an active transaction'.

I don't want to (and don't think I need to) show much code, but here is pretty much what is going on.
crawl.php

```
$this->dbh; // connect
$this->dbh->beginTransaction();
$this->doStuff->execute(); // does rollback
$Notifications = new Notifications($id,$this->dbh);
```

notifications.php

```
function __construct($id,$dbh) {
   $this->dbh = $dbh;
   // $this->dbh->beginTransaction(); -- transaction already started
   $this->addRows->execute(); // does not roll back
   $this->dbh->rollBack();
   exit;
}
```

**UPDATE 1**
I tried querying 'SET autocommit=0' and then 'ROLLBACK' but I got the same results.

**UPDATE 2**
I used the following code to check to see if the notification class was in a transaction, and it not surprisingly outputted 'in transaction'.

```
 if($this->dbh->inTransaction()) {
    echo 'in transaction';
 }
```

**UPDATE 3**
Final update, hopefully.  The PDO queries made from notifications.php are inserting into a DIFFERENT InnoDB table.  Would this be a problem?

Any ideas?

Comment: Note: it doesn't matter if the rollBack()/exit calls are made from the Notifications class or the original Crawl class.  Both rollback all changes in crawl.php and none in notifications.php

Comment: I assume you include the notifications.php. It should be regardless which functions rolls back your transaction. Everything within a single transaction should be rolled back. I can only imagine, that there is a commit anywhere in your other functions which are called before the rollback is called.

Comment: @BenjaminPaap, thanks for the help..I just double checked and the only commit() is called at the very end of the script (I have rollBack() and exit before this is ever called).  Do you mind checking Update 3, I think that may be the culprit.

Comment: Update #3 can't be the problem. I checked with my test script and it also worked with a second table. Check this page if something in between causes an implicit commit: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/implicit-commit.html

Comment: @BenjaminPaap, thanks for all your help (the link was a great resource).  But it was a stupid mistake, I will post an answer soon.  It just shows its been too long of a work week.

Answer (score 0):

I have been upgrading my database structure and rewriting a lot of the backend code, and had forgotten to change the Notification table from MyISAM to InnoDB.  Thanks to BenjaminPaap for the help/interest.

Sorry for the wasted question.